# Qt Design Promoted Qpushbutton parameterised constructor

Tags: qt, designer

I've been learning about subclassing and widget promotion in Qt Designer and I've promoted some QPushButtons. My promoted class represents the number keys on a calculator, and takes a parameter in the constructor.  The parameter given is the number of the button and it is passed in as an int.

Is there a way to tell Qt Designer how to construct each button? The constructor needs the numbers 0-9 passed to it. If I manually modify the generated code it works; however, each time it generates the form, I have to manually edit it.

Comment: The runtime info that you pass to the button via constructor will not show up in the designer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no simple way to achieve this while keeping your argument in the constructor I'm afraid (read [this page in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) to how you might go about it).

I think your best solution is to keep the constructor mirroring that of `QPushButton` (i.e. just passing a parent `QWidget`) and set your custom data by calling a function afterwards.